# Is there a way to optimize MYSQL REPLACE function?

Tags: python, mysql, replace, sqlalchemy

I need to develop a query to find `MF001317-077944-01` in the database, but the string provided(which I must use to search), is without the `-`.

So I am currently using:

```
select * from sims where replace(pack, "-", "") = "MF00131707794401";
```

sqlAlchemy equivalent:

```
s.query(Sims).filter(func.replace(Sims.pack, "-", "") == "MF00131707794401").all()
```

But it is taking to long. It is taking, on average 1min 22s, I need to get is well under 1 second.

I have considered using wildcards, but I do not know if that is the best way of approaching my problem.

Is there a way to optimize the `replace` query? 
or is there a better way of achieving what I want i.e, manipulating the string in python to get `MF001317-077944-01`?

oh.. I should also mention that it might not always be the same, for example, two different pack numbers might be `XAN002-026-001` or `CK10000579-020-3`.

Any help would be appreciated `:)`.

Comment: unfortunately no, even if `pack` is indexed then it will fail to use it for the given where clause.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty thanks for your response, is there not another way to achieve this in mysql?

Comment: One way is to have another column in the DB which is indexed and store all the strings without `-`, which you can do before inserting, then the query will go on that column and since its indexed it will be guaranteed much much better.

Comment: Can you use - in the to be searched string by understanding conventions, so that both the string follow the same pattern. on the other hand you can index the column "pack" in mysql.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty The table is quite a big one, so I will in the future, normalize the table a bit more, so that I can have this easily, how ever I do not have enough time allocated to this task to do it. so I am looking for a simple fix, for now.

@Haseena I do not entirely understand what you are saying, but the `pack` column is indexed `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You must find a way to avoid a table scan.

Several Options:

1) create an index on your "pack" column and put the "-" into the search String before Querying. Will only work when you know where to put the "-" in the search string (e.g. when they always at the same positions). This is the easiest way.

2) create an additional column "pack_search". Fill it with replace(pack, "-", ""). Create an INSERT OR UPDATE Trigger to update its value when rows are updated or inserted. Create an Index on that column and use that column for your query.

3) nicer: create a View on the table with a modified pack column and an Index on that view (dunno if that works on mysql, postgres can definitely do that). Use that view vor your Query. For further speedup you could materialize that view if the table is much more read than written or if a lag is ok for the query results (e.g. if the table is updated nightly and you query for an Online Service).

4) maybe it can be done by using a functional Index